# Update a Widget when user switches to sleep mode

Tags: android, widget

I have created a little app with a widget, and I want to widget to update when the user switches to sleep mode (or whatever the mode is called when you short-push the power button).

I have searched around to no avail. I tried registering a `BroadcastReceiver`, but that is not allowed in a Widget.

If it is not possible, it means the widget has to wait for the `updatePeriodMillis` timeout, but that's at least 30 minutes and it kind of breaks the user experience.

Comment: You can use a BroadcastReceiver and manually start your widget-update-service. This also allows you to bypass the updatePeriodMillis treshold.

Comment: There is no service currently. To implement a service just for this one function, feels a little too much.

Comment: "I have created a little app with a widget, and I want to widget to update when the user switches to sleep mode" -- since, by definition, the user cannot see the app widget when the screen is off, this seems pointless. Moreover, you would have no choice but to try to keep a service running 24x7 just to find out when the screen turns off (or on), which users may not appreciate.

Comment: @CommonsWare: I'll elaborate a little, I don't want it to update **while** the screen is off, but when the screen **switches** to off mode. I just want to catch that certain event. And I agree with you on the 24x7 service which users won't appreciate.